# Error in removeRow in JButton

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

I Had an Error in Clear the `JTable` Content using `JButton` . Here is my Code .

```
private void ClearCartBTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

   try{
       DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)Cart_table.getModel();  //Cart_table (Var Name of Jtable)

       while(model.getRowCount()>0){
           for(int i= 0 ; i <model.getRowCount();i++){
               model.removeRow(i);
           }
       }

   }catch(Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
   }

}
```

Only I had an Error in `model.removeRow(i)`;

What should I do ?

Comment: What kind of error and what is the message?

Comment: it has a redline or errorline for model.removeRow(i); which says cannot find symbol  , symbol :method removeRow(int)

Comment: what is stacktrace ? Hahaha  . sorry because I'm a beginner in netbeans

Comment: It is a compile error, so you have no stacktrace.

Comment: Can you show the import statement of `DefaultTableModel`?

Comment: So , What  should I do ?

Comment: import groovy.model.DefaultTableModel; here sir ?

Comment: Remove the rows in reverse order

Comment: It should be `import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel`

Comment: If you're using javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel, you can use setRowCount and pass it 0

Comment: Thanks a lot to all you , the error has gone  . but I it doesn't clear the Table content :( . Can you help me ? Can you Give me another process to Clear the Content in the JTable  using JButton .

Comment: You have to refresh the table, you can use `model.fireTableDataChanged()` to do that.

Comment: I doesn't clear or update in Database in MS Access :(